# How to fix String output in Java: com.offbytwo.jenkins.model.Build@15888e2

Tags: java, jenkins

I am programming using Java to connect to Jenkins instance and fetch/post few information. I am using jar which allows me to use methods directly to fetch information about job(name of job, pass/fail status, job description etc). When I use any method which return boolean or number or url, it works fine. But when return type is String it gives me output in a different format.

Find the code below:

```
import com.offbytwo.jenkins.*;
import com.offbytwo.jenkins.client.*;
import com.offbytwo.jenkins.model.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Map;

public class NewTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        System.out.println("begin");
        JenkinsServer server = new JenkinsServer(new URI("https://my-jenkins.abc.com/job/MyJobs/job/Dev/job/Test/"), "userid", "token");

        Map<String, Job> jobs = server.getJobs();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Job> entry : jobs.entrySet())
        {

            String name = entry.getKey();
            JobWithDetails jobdet = jobs.get(name).details();
            System.out.println("Job Links");
            System.out.println(jobdet.getUrl());
            System.out.println("Next Build Number");
            System.out.println(jobdet.getNextBuildNumber());
            System.out.println("Detail by build number");
            System.out.println(jobdet.getBuildByNumber(1));


        }

    }
```

Output:

```
after begin
Job Links
https://my-jenkins.abc.com/job/MyJobs/job/Dev/job/Test/job/git_test/
Next Build Number
4
Detail by build number
com.offbytwo.jenkins.model.Build@15888e2
```

How do I get "Detail by build number" in proper format? I used toString() function but it threw me error.I was getting same format error with `JobWithDetails jobdet = jobs.get(name).details();`

```
JobWithDetails jobdet = jobs.get(name).details().toString();
```

It still gives me following output:

```
com.offbytwo.jenkins.model.Build@15888e2
```

I tried defining toString() separately but I did not know what should I return and toString() I defined outside cannot access variables inside main function. How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: have u got any answer to it?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to print the entire `Build` object, which (as you've noticed) does not have `toString()` overridden.  Thus it prints the unhelpful stuff you see there.

You need to decide what property(ies) of `Build` you want to print.  If, for example, it's the build URL that you want, you will want to print this:

```
System.out.println(jobdet.getBuildByNumber(1).getUrl());
```

Comment: Thank you Joe. I see that .getUrl() is listing in the function getBuildByNumber() but it throws me error. And when I try with "jobdet = jobs.get(name).details().toString();" it gives me that unformatted output.